# Filling Form Fields Automatically

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, combobox

Hi I asked this question again but since it was not well answered, hence I am asking it again:

I have a table Exhibit_Testing with the following fields:

1) ReferenceNo ( Automatic Number) 2) Region_Name 3) Branch_Code 4)Branch_Name 5) AOM 6) Observation 7) Status 8) Date_Recieved 9) Date_Checked

I want to create a Data Entry Form where if I enter Branch_Code then, Region_Name, Branch_Name, AOM are automatically filled.

Please help me in that. Thanks.

Update : The Branch_Code should be in Combo Box format.

Comment: If region_name, etc can be automatically filled (=deducted) from branch_code, then your database is not normalized: it does not respect the second normal form ....

Comment: Of course, it's not really your problem but my experience says 'never develop anything (and specifically data entry form) on an unnormalized database ....

Comment: yes I agree with you on this one.

Comment: Instead of creating a new question you should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19763095/edit) your existing question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the "`afterUpdate`" event of the Branch_Code `combo box`. In this procedure, you will set the values of the Region_Name, Branch_Name, AOM `controls` or `fields` (if these are bound controls) depending on the updated value for Branch_Code.

This said, if you have another `table` (or `view`) containing the Branch_Code, Region_Name, Branch_Name, AOM values, you can ajust the display of your `combobox` in such a way that the complete string (Branch_Code + Region_Name + Branch_Name + AOM) is displayed in the combobox. You will not need the other controls anymore.